# Prototype.js conflicting with jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, selectize.js

My application has been using prototype.js for a while. I am now trying to use jQuery and a jquery plugin for some enhanced functionality. However prototype.js and jQuery produce a conflict for the use of the '$' variable. This can ofcourse be resolved by the noConflict() method provided by jQuery and hence I can change the jQuery shortcut to what I want. The problem is how do I use the jQuery plugin which I want to import. Surely there is a better way than finding and replacing all the '$' variables.

The plugin being used is 'Selectize' https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js

Comment: Does it work if you replace all $ variables?

Comment: To which plugin do you refer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've edited your question to say:

> The plugin being used is 'Selectize' https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js

That plugin doesn't rely on the global `$` symbol at all; there's nothing you need to do to make the plugin compatible with a site that uses `$` for something else (such as Prototype). The plugin only relies on the `jQuery` symbol. (It uses `$` internally, but only as a local variable; it doesn't use the global.) Any properly-written jQuery plugin avoids using the global `$`, because of this very issue.

To use that on your site, you'd do something like this:

```
<script src="/path/to/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/your/code.js></script>
```

...where your code might look like this:

```
(function() {
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j("some-selector").pluginMethod();  // jQuery
    $("some-id").addClassName("foo");    // Prototype
})();
```

*(You don't* need *the wrapper function there, it's just to avoid creating a `$j` global).*

Or just:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery("some-selector").pluginMethod();  // jQuery
$("some-id").addClassName("foo");        // Prototype
```

Comment: @Zeutheus: No worries, glad that helped. (Your bad? Not following, your question was perfectly reasonable.)

Answer (score 0):

I think T.J. Crowder has a good answer, but as an alternative if you need to manage conflicts etc across your entire project. You may wish to consider requirejs.

I won't go into detail about [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) as plenty can be found on it's site.

RequireJS is a module loader to help manage problems like this and has features to help with javascript that does not adhere to the [asynchronous module pattern](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html).

Here is an article discussing it's use with jQuery and plugins. http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html